# How to add shadow under custom action bar in pre-lollipop device?

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, shadow

I have a custom action bar defined in `layout_action_bar.xml` (refer below). In every fragment, if I want to use that action bar, I will use it like a custom widget in their respective xml layout file.

I have tried the below methods to add a shadow below the action bar:

1. Used `android:elevation` (refer below) but it did not work on pre-lollipop device.
2. Used custom view as shadow after the navigation bar (refer below) but the shadow inserted will disrupt the display of contents below the action bar. I want the shadow to overlay the content.
3. There are methods mentioned in stackoverflow such as using the `CardView` widget to create a shadow effect but I do not want my custom action bar to become a card view.

**layout_action_bar.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/actionbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        ...ImageView and TextView for action bar...

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_below="@id/actionbar"
        style="@style/shadowStyle"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Example on how I use the custom action bar in a fragment's layout xml file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.test.views.CustomActionBarView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    ...fragment's content here...

</LinearLayout>
```